# JQuery waypoints with analytics tracking getting page URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, analytics, tracking

I am trying to implement a tracking event for when my user scrolls to the bottom of an article page on my website using JQuery waypoints plugin (http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/), but am having trouble firing the event when I bring the URL of the page into the event. It works fine without the URL, but the URL of the page is needed so I can see which article is being read.

It is also a requirement that the event is only fired once per visit (which is what the  event.stopPropagation();}, {triggerOnce: true,offset: 'bottom-in-view'}); is for.

The JQuery code is below:

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.simonholmes.co.uk/js/waypoints.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(event) {
$('#lcol2').waypoint(function() {
    var PageURL = window.location.pathname;
       _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Article Test Event', 'Scrolled to end of article', PageURL ,'DATA HERE']);
          event.stopPropagation();
            }, {
                triggerOnce: true,
                offset: 'bottom-in-view'
            });
 });
</script>
```

Thanks for any ideas and help,

Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was in the

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Article Test Event', 'Scrolled to end of article', PageURL ,'DATA HERE']);
```

part of the code. The final variable 'DATA HERE' had to be either be an integer, or left blank as stated in http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html, and not a string, which was causing the event to not work.

Thanks for your help anyway Diodeus.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to convert a [location object](http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javalocation.html) so it can be consumed as a string.

```
var PageURL = window.location.pathname + "";
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you response. Unfortunately that didnt seem to work. When I scroll to the bottom of the page it just wont fire the tacking script. In the firefbu console I get an error stating 'a.stopPropagation is not a function'. But only when trying to load the PageURL.